# Jquery UI range slider displaying wrong max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I have slider like this,

```
                    var max=Number(data[0].max);
                    var min=Number(data[0].min);
$("#slider-range-"+field_name ).empty().slider({
                  range: true,
                  min: min,
                  max: max,
                  step:step_value,
                  values: [ 0, max],
                  slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#"+$(this).data("id")).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                  }
                }).slider("pips", {

                        rest: false

                }).slider("float", {

                    handle: true,
                    pips: false,
                    labels: false,
                    prefix: "",
                    suffix: ""

                });

                $("#"+field_name).val( $( "#slider-range-"+field_name ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - "
                  +  $( "#slider-range-"+field_name ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Here, If I pass value as max like max = 3.6, slider will display max as 3.59999999996. But If I pass hardcore value then it will display properly.
Why it is behving like this? Is there any library issue, But I have already changed my library version also. If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: How are you pass the value? There might be javascript issue as, for 1.1 + 2.2 javascript returns the value 3.3000000000000003

Comment: I have updated my question, now you can see...